# Why is drone.io keeping information of previous runs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drone.io

I want to delete all previous information of drone and make a completely new installation. So what I'm doing is this.

With this dockerfile:

```
version: '2'

services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:0.8

    ports:
      - 80:8000
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone/
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_OPEN=true
      - DRONE_HOST=http://drone-server:8000
      - DRONE_GITEA=true
      - DRONE_GITEA_URL=http://web:3000
      - DRONE_SECRET=${DRONE_SECRET}
  drone-agent:
    image: drone/agent:0.8

    command: agent
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER=drone-server:9000
      - DRONE_SECRET=${DRONE_SECRET}
  web:
    image: gitea/gitea:1.3.2
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "22:22"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
  db:
    image: mariadb:10
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=gitea
      - MYSQL_USER=gitea
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=changeme
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/var/lib/mysql
```

I'm made a `docker-compose up`
Then to delete everything I made a `docker-compose down`. And make sure to delete every volume and every container manually. But when I do `docker-compose up` again the old information is still there. Why? Where is drone getting that information? I'm new with drone and docker so probably I'm doing something wrong because this does not make sense. Maybe I'm forgetting to delete something.
Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drone stores details about its runs in an SQLite db in `/var/lib/drone` by default, which you have mounted as a volume, so the stuff it saves in there is kept on your machine when you spin things down and passed back to the new containers when you create them.

If you want to completely reset everything you need to remove the files in your host machines `/var/lib/drone` folder too.

Comment: That's it. Thank you.